# Изолированное выполнение Java

Tags: sandbox, java, плагин

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос общего плана, так как пока пытаюсь собрать в кучу мысли и определится с инструментарием.

Есть (будет:)) ядро приложения, которое взаимодействует с файловой системой, базой данных, сетью. Для увеличения его функционала планируется использование "модулей расширения". Основная задача модулей - получить от ядра данные, каким-то образом их обработать, вернуть результат.

Само собой, очень хочется, чтоб модули имели как можно меньше возможностей шариться там, где им явно не разрешили...
Если бы речь не шла о кросс-платформе, я бы наверно удовлетворился *nix-chroot'ом - каждой хрени по изолированной середе (+,возможно, по отдельному пользователю) и в своих рамках хай творят, что хотят.
Вариант разработки своей интерпретируемой среды с кучей предметных объектов и языком.. наверно, в теории, тоже может рассматриваться, но уже попахивает извращениями в стиле 1С))

Вопрос - можно ли каким-либо образом запускать java-классы в среде... ну примерно так, как это делает браузер для апплетов? Или может как-то можно уменьшить набор системных классов для модуля (естественно предоставив аналогичные, но фильтруемые)...

Буду рад услышать идеи, соображения, ссылки на литературу...

Спасибо!

Comment: Проблема сокращения пачки классов из JVM - давно является краеугольным камнем, в чем собственно проблема: Изначально SUN задумывала, что JAVA едина, т.е. у каждого на машине есть JVM и соответственно у каждого есть набор классов JVM, так не вышло ...тупо реазть тоже не получится, ведь если Вы взгляните на зависимости,  то это макароны. Вот тут запись с конференции Java ONE на эту тему:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKWlp8UQQb4
Вообще они все обещают сделать jigsaw...ждем)

Comment: <offtopic>В .NET для таких целей есть AppDomain: как бы кусок приложения, который (1) выполняется с отдельными правами, (2) можно весь целиком выгрузить в любой момент, (3) при креше валится не всё приложение, а только AppDomain, где произошёл креш</offtopic>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну можно конечно извратиться и запустить 2 копии JVM, в одной JVM крутится ваше ядро, а во второй ваши плагины. Взаимодействие между ядром и плагинами организовать через RMI

Comment: И плагины в chroot'е, если оно будет стабильно работать в итоге. Что-то такое я и думал.

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, вам пригодится кастомный `ClassLoader`, чтобы устанавить нужный  `ProtectionDomain`.

Ссылки: [[1]](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/26/javavsdotnet.html?page=2), [[2]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/class-use/ProtectionDomain.html).